# Azure B2C signin over AD

Tags: .net, azure, azure-ad-b2c

i have question about Azure B2C sign in. I have my Tenant1 where is enabled local account (email/password) thats working perfect. I would like have second way - invite user from another AD. I can invite user from another AD to my "B2C" - users is stored in local AD. And for now i have two ways how to sign in.

1. Create in application B2C flow and sign in to AD with openid
2. I tried add my AD to B2C flow as identity provider and it works for half. When invite user i try sign in with him and it mark him like user from external user ad and create empty user with name uknown

What's correct way or why do this better? Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For invitation via application kindly follow https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/invite/README.md
- While adding a user by adding Azure AD as an IDP kindly follow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow
- It mark him like user from external user ad and create empty user with name unknown, The user will be shown external as its IDP is Azure AD and Azure B2C tenant is the resource provider only. The user name shows unknown could be because the following claims vale would have been incorrect from IDP configuration:

User ID: oid Display name: name Given name: given_name Surname: family_name Email: email

[image]

Thanks